# CSRF verification failed. Request aborted when clicking on the register button

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I am creating a basic registration and login page in Django. But When I click on the register button after filling information, it gives me error:

> CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.

I am using Django 1.10.5 and python 3.4

**views.py**

```
from app.forms import *
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.auth import logout
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_protect
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.template import RequestContext

@csrf_protect
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = User.objects.create_user(
            username=form.cleaned_data['username'],
            password=form.cleaned_data['password1'],
            email=form.cleaned_data['email']
            )
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/register/success/')
    else:
        form = RegistrationForm()
    variables = RequestContext(request, {
    'form': form
    })

    return render_to_response(
    'registration/register.html',
    variables,
    )

def register_success(request):
    return render_to_response(
    'registration/success.html',
    )

def logout_page(request):
    logout(request)
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')

@login_required
def home(request):
    return render_to_response(
    'home.html',
    { 'user': request.user }
    )
```

**Register.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}User Registration{% endblock %}
{% block head %}User Registration{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
    <form method="post" action=".">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <table border="0">
        {{ form.as_table }}
        </table>
        <input type="submit" value="Register" />
    </form>
    <a href="/">Login</a>
{% endblock %}
```

**settings.py**

```
import os
import posixpath

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '5c1fdaf0-d355-4328-9033-693273effc03'

import django.contrib.auth
django.contrib.auth.LOGIN_URL = '/'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [

# Add your apps here to enable them
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'app'
]

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'myapp.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
  },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'myapp.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
    'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
  }
}


 # Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#auth-password-    validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
       'NAME':   'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
   },
  {
       'NAME':  'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
   {
      'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
   },
  {
    'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
  },
 ]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

 TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

 USE_I18N = True

 USE_L10N = True

 USE_TZ = True


 STATIC_URL = '/static/'

 STATIC_ROOT = posixpath.join(*(BASE_DIR.split(os.path.sep) + ['static']))
```

I am not sure what is causing this error because I am using @csrf_protect and also using render properly.

Please guide me.

Comment: Stop using `RequestContext` manually, e.g. `variables = {'form': form}`. The use `render` instead of `render_to_response`, e.g. `return render(request, 'registration/register.html', variables)`.

Comment: it is giving the same error, I tried to debug and put a breakpoint at register function, I found that it is not even hitting at the register function

Comment: and when I am using render instead of render_to_response, it gives me error that no define name render

Comment: Ok, solved it. I have imported render.. Thanks a lot